# Designing an Algorithm to find the length of a simple cycle in a d-regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

[image]

I understand the question in general but don't know how to design and analyze the algorithm in the question. I was thinking of applying some sort of graph search algorithm like depth-first / breadth-first search.

Comment: Instead of posting an image, you should type up that question. (This makes this post more easily indexed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply DFS to solve this problem. In a $d$-regular graph all nodes have degree $d$. Assume the algorithm is started at $v_1$.

- Since $v_1$ has $d$ neighbors, there is an unvisited node $v_2$ and the DFS continues at this node.
- Since $v_2$ has $d$ neighbors and only 1 node has been visited so far, there is an unvisited node $v_3$ and the DFS continues at this node.
- ...

This scheme can be continued until $d$ nodes have been considered.

- When $v_{d+1}$ is considered and $v_1$ is a neighbor of $v_{d+1}$ then the desired cycle is found. Otherwise there must be an unvisited neighbor and the DFS continues.
- When $v_{d+2}$ is considered and $v_1$ or $v_2$ is a neighbor of $v_{d+2}$ then the desired cycle is found. Otherwise there must be an unvisited neighbor and the DFS continues.
- ...

This algorithm will eventually find a simple cycle of length at least $d + 1$.